# Python read from file that has multiple values

Tags: python

```
Ben
5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 -3 5 0 0 0 5 5 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 0 1 0 -5 0 0 5 5 0 5 5 5 0 5 5 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 -5 
Moose
5 5 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 1 0 5 3 0 5 0 3 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 -3 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 5 0 3 0 0 
Reuven
```

I was wondering how to read multiple lines of this sort of file into a list or dictionary as I want the ratings which are the numbers to stay with the names of the person that corresponds with the rating

Comment: Please be more focused and provide your attempts at your problem. Are you having trouble with reading the file? with storing the data? help us help you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list

Comment: would there be ratings for Reuven be expected in the 6th line of the file?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the file in pairs of two lines and populate a dictionary.

```
path = ... # path to your file
out = {}
with open(path) as f:
    # iterate over lines in the file
    for line in f:
        # the first, 3rd, ... line contains the name
        name = line
        # the 2nd, 4th, ... line contains the ratings
        ratings = f.next() # by calling next here, we jump two lines per iteration
        # write values to dictionary while using strip to get rid of whitespace
        out[name.strip()] = [int(rating.strip()) for rating in ratings.strip().split(' ')]
```

It could also be done with a while loop:

```
path = ... # path to your file
out = {}
with open(path) as f:
    while(True):
        # read name and ratings, which are in consecutive lines
        name = f.readline()
        ratings = f.readline()
        # stop condition: end of file is reached
        if name == '':
            break
        # write values to dictionary:
        # use name as key and convert ratings to integers. 
        # use strip to get rid of whitespace
        out[name.strip()] = [int(rating.strip()) for rating in ratings.strip().split(' ')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip to combine lines by pairs to form the dictionary

```
with open("file.txt","r") as f:
    lines = f.read().split("\n")
    d = { n:[*map(int,r.split())] for n,r in zip(lines[::2],lines[1::2]) }
```